# webpack 4 - can't find /package.json in production mode

Tags: webpack, google-cloud-firestore, webpack-4

I'm running webpack4 for a simple web express application
When I'm running the server in development environment (via nodemon) it's running perfectly, but when I'm going into production I'm getting this weird error (generated from a firestore line)

`Error: package.json does not exist at /package.json`

I can't figure out why it's looking for the package.json in the root (/) directory instead of the dist directory.

This is my webpack.config.js file:

```
// webpack.config.js

const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack') // to access built-in plugins
// const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')

const config = {
  mode: 'production',
  target: 'node',
  entry: './lib/index.js',
  // externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.txt$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: 'raw-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: './lib/assets/lastest.txt' }, { from: './package.json' }]),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
    }),
  ]
}

module.exports = config
```

any ideas what am I missing?
I saw in the documentation a reference to Resolvers but by default, it's looking for package.json so...

Comment: have the same issue, did you solve?

Answer (score 0):

Just solved a similar issue:

**One.** Setup aliases in your`webpack.config.js` like so:

```
...
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.json'],
  modules: ['node_modules'],
  alias: {
    "@/routes": path.resolve(__dirname, "routes"),
}
```

**Two.** Inform your TS/JS compiler of the module aliases, eg. in `jsconfig.json`:

```
"paths": {
  "@/*": ["./*"]
}
```

**(Optional)** Don't `require('module-alias/register')`? This won't work with Webpack v5. Rather, hook into `module-alias` manually:

```
const moduleAlias = require('module-alias')
moduleAlias.addAliases({
     "@": __dirname
})
```

Please let me know how it went for you. Rgds.

Answer (score -1):

The issue comes from a problem with gRPC (a dependency of firebase/firestore), which has trouble finding bindings from node-pre-gyp (it's dependency) on Windows.   So instead of importing Firebase like this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

you need to import firebase by creating an App Shell use script tags like this:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.0/firebase-app.js" />
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.0/firebase-firestore.js" />
```

With this workaround, you can cache these scripts to your user's browser. However, this will result in increased loading times *only* for the first time your user enters your website. Other than that, the website should actually run just as fast (maybe even faster). You don't even need to bother creating an external API (unless that's what you'd like to do). To access your database, you can do a simple `firebase.firestore()...get()` but make sure your user has Firebase installed in their cache before you try something like this or you will get an error stating that `firebase.firestore()` is not a function.